# Loading Pandas Data Frame with Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to load a data frame from a large csv file as shown below. Currently, this line fails due to an out of memory error. I would like to use the multiprocessing package (from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool) when loading from this csv file. Here is what I am trying to run using Multiprocessing:

```
source_data_df = pd.read_csv(temp_file, skipinitialspace=True, dtype=str, na_values=['N.A.'])
```

Could someone show how this line and the additional code would look when running with Multiprocessing?

Big thank you!

Michael

Comment: Why do you think using multiprocessing will solve `Out of Memory` error. Whether a single Python holds the entire dataframe or multiple processes hold chunks of the dataframe, the total memory required to hold all the data will be more or less the same.

Comment: please take a look at option `chunksize` as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas.